# Levantar servicios con docker-compose utilizando crontab

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, crontab

Estoy realizando pruebas **aprendiendo** y me he topado con un problema

tengo un Dockerfile super básico para crear una imagen basada en Python y copia los archivos..

```
ENV TZ=America/Panama
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install vim -y


RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x /app/scheduler.sh
```

adicional tengo un docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 main.py"
```

Hasta el momento todo esto funciona bien no hay problema, pero quiero levantar el servició **app** cada 1 minuto.

**PROBLEMA**

La ejecución para levantar el servicio lo tengo en un shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Iniciando proceso"
sh -c "cd /home/miusuario/hora"
sh -c "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose run app"
```

y el programado un crontab, pero hay es donde tengo un el problema

```
*/1 * * * *  /home/miusuario/hora/app/scheduler.sh >> /home/miusuario/hora/app/log.log
```

El crontab se ejecuta porque en el log se muestra la salida del mensaje `echo "Iniciando proceso"`, pero el servicio nunca se levanta, no muestra error.

PD: he ejecutado el `scheduler.sh` directo desde consola y realiza las instrucciones (levantar el servicio), al igual que si ejecuta `docker run nombredelaimagen` pero el problema es que específicamente desde el crontab no realiza la ejecución de la instrucción del crontab.

Y ya no se que pueda ser, ya que no me muestra mensajes de error.
Gracias

Comment: El `scheduler.sh` que se ejecuta con el cron,  no es el mismo archivo ni el mismo entorno que el creado con el contenedor que se crearía con el Dockerfile que indicas, eso es asi deliberadamente?

Comment: @Emeeus El `scheduler.sh` se encuentra en una subcarpeta en el directorio donde he creado Dockerfile, lo que tengo sospechas es que al ejecutar la instrucción de docker-compose no lo encuentra en el sistema, ya que si creo un contenedor con docker no tengo problemas (Lo ejecuta normal con docker)